# Regression on beta coefficients from different models

Tags: regression, linear-model, error

**Brief Background:**
Let's say I performed different regression models and found their beta coefficients estimates with their corresponding variances.

I would now want to do a regression on those beta coefficient estimates, along with some other data...my goal is to use a combination of the beta estimates to classify something as "yes, no, maybe". I would take the beta estimates and do an OLS as if they were raw data points.

**My question is:** 
How do I account for the error of the original beta coefficients into my final error?

Comment: By "beta", do you mean *standardized* coefficients? I think SPSS calls them that. Also, are you trying to do meta-analysis?

Comment: Yes I do mean the standardized coefficients, they are one and the same yes? Can you define meta-analysis for me?

Comment: Be aware that outside of SPSS, regular old coefficients are called "betas" & standardized coefficients are called "standardized betas". Meta-analysis is where you are analyzing the results of analyses (effect sizes, correlations, etc). Are the standardized betas you are referring to the results of prior studies?

Comment: Yes these betas are results of prior studies. I basically want to see if the combination of betas of prior studies can predict results of the current study.

For example let's say that I get a beta of +5 for study_1 and a beta of -2 for study_2. Can the +/- combination of study_1 and study_2 predict a certain trend in study_3? IF so what is the final error?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. If you are talking about standardized betas, they are bounded by [-1, 1].

Comment: Ok sorry...so what about for unstandardized coefficients? Standardized or unstandardized, I would still like to know how these errors propagate to the final error. Could we speak about this in a general mathematical sense and not bound to any particular statistical software?